# nftables ip6 route to localhost/ ipv6 nat to loopback

Tags: ipv6, nftables

I'm trying to route incoming http internet traffic to [::1]:8080 which is where my http server binds to. I'm using nftables on an IPv6-only device. If I add following rules:

```sh
  sudo nft flush ruleset
  sudo nft add table ip6 nat
  sudo nft add chain ip6 nat prerouting { type nat hook prerouting priority 0 \; }
  sudo nft add chain ip6 nat postrouting { type nat hook postrouting priority 100 \; }

  sudo nft add rule ip6 nat prerouting ip6 daddr [global-ip6] tcp dport 80 dnat to ::1 :8080

  sudo nft list ruleset
```

with resulting ruleset:

```
table ip6 nat {
  chain prerouting {
    type nat hook prerouting priority 0; policy accept;
    ip6 daddr [global-ip6] tcp dport http dnat to [::1]:http-alt
  }

  chain postrouting {
    type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
  }
}
```

then requests to [global-ip6]:80 get swallowed (there is no connection refused error) but no connection is established.

If I use one of the rules

```
sudo nft add rule ip6 nat prerouting tcp dport 80 redirect to 8080
```

or

```
sudo nft add rule ip6 nat prerouting ip6 daddr [global-ip6] tcp dport 80 dnat to [global-ip6] :8080
```

and bind my program to `[global-ip6]:8080`, then communication works as expected.

Do you have an idea what I am missing? I tried out some rules in the `postrouting` and `input` chains but couldn't get it to work. Back with IPv4 and iptables I had to do `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1`, maybe there is a similar IPv6 flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot achieve what you want with the nftables.

After the dnat target the destination address is rewritten to the loopback address (`::1`), and then the incoming packet is processed by the routing code. But any incoming packet with the loopback destination address has been received from outside MUST be dropped by [RFC 4291 2.5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.3). [There aren't any `sysctl` variables to change this behavior.](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/ipv6/ip6_input.c#L179)

You can run some proxy app, that will be accept connection on the external address and connects to the application that listens the loopback address.

Comment: Thank you very much! The two links you provided are convincing. For those interested I checked how IPv4 handles local routing and you can find the effect of the sysctl flag here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/ipv4/route.c#L2056 .
I guess I'll be going with the global-ip6 then.