# Why does ip6tables lose packets after PREROUTING to a different interface?

Tags: iptables, docker, routing, nat, ipv6

I'm using `ip6tables` to nat packages to an IP on a different interface (localhost), but all packets sent there are lost.
I have the same `iptables` rules for IPv4 where everything is working fine.

## Setup

The host is a debian 11 VM, the client is a docker container running `debian:stable-slim`.

`/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```json
{
   "ipv6": true,
   "fixed-cidr-v6": "2d00::/8",
   "ip6tables": true,
   "experimental": true
}
```

The host has the `docker0` interface IPs `2d00::1` and `172.17.0.2` for IPv6 and IPv4 respectively.
I'm setting up the following ip(6)tables rules to NAT for IPv4 and IPv6 respectively:

```
ip6tables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 2d00::1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8081 -j DNAT --to-destination [::1]:9999
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 172.17.0.2 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8081 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:9999
```

I have also appended the following rules to my `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

## Minimal non-working example

Set up an HTTP server on the host, listening on `[::1]:9999`:

```
python3 -m http.server --bind ::1 9999
```

And try to connect to it from a client container:

```
docker run --rm -it --name client debian:stable-slim /bin/bash
apt update
apt install -y curl
curl http://[2d00::1]:8081
```

The result is that curl hangs for a while and continuously tries to establish a connection, but i never get a response.

## Things i have tried and observed

I have done the same test as in the non-working example above for

- IPv4 with nat
- IPv6 without nat
- IPv6 with nat to an IP on the same interface as the original destination IP (i.e. just change the port, or NAT to the interface's link-local address)

and they *all succeeded*.
So the only non-working case is IPv6 with NAT where the NAT wants to route to a different interface.

I have also added log outputs to various ip(6)tables chains and i could see that in the successful cases, i can observe packets arriving at the `filter` table's `INPUT` chain, as well as the `nat` table's `PREROUTING` chain.
As soon as i try to NAT IPv6 traffic to a different interface, i no longer get any packets arriving at any chain in the `filter` table.

I have also used `tcpdump` to track packets on the host, and observed that in the successful cases i see the packets at the `veth*` virtual interfaces created by docker, as well as on the `docker0` interface.
When doing the NAT to a different interface on IPv6, the packets no longer appear at the `docker0` interface, but i still see them at the `veth*` interface.

Comment: Have you enabled IPv6 forwarding on the host at `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, yes i have! I also listed the (afaik) relevant kernel parameters above as part of my `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging i found out that the problem is not cross-interface routing, but routing to `::1`, which [this answer to a different thread](https://serverfault.com/a/975890/1003788) has shown me, is not allowed in IPv6 as per RFC 4291 Section 2.5.3.